# how to stop checking out automatically in tfs when source is edited in VS 2010

Tags: .net, version-control

I am new to tfs.
I am checking out a file by right click and check out in solution explorer.
But if try to alter the any file it is automatically checking out.
how to prevent this ?

And i need to set locking type as **Prevent other users from checkin and check out**

How to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

VS->Tools>Options> Select Source Control under options. Select Environment under Source Control. Now under Checked-in Items->Editing-> Select Do noting

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting in Tools | Options | Source Control | Environment that controls automatic checkout of edited files

Answer (score 0):

Find the file in Windows Explorer, and modifying the properties of it by turning off the Read-Only flag.

This is not recommended though as Visual Studio will not block you from modifying the file, nor will it check it in when you do perform a code check in.

One way for Visual Studio to detect the file change is when your TFS connection is brought Online from an Offline state and the wizard runs looking for non Read-Only files in the solution, then marks those files as checked out.